# How to attach SelectedItem event through xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to attach to each `ListView` items the selected item event through xaml, what I did is this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListViewItem}">
   <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                         Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
 </Style>
```

the problem's that this event isn't fired if I do:

```
myListView.SelectedItem = myItem;
```

but fire the event `ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` only when the user click on the single row. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) Event.

```
<ListView SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged"/>
```